# Proving the limit does not exist for $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x+\sin(x) \cos(x)}{e^{\sin(x)}(x+\sin(x) \cos(x))}$

Tags: limits, solution-verification

I want to show that following limit does not exist:

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-\sin x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)
$$

I know that the smallest possible value for this function is when it takes following form:
$$
\frac{1}{e}
$$
and the biggest possible value:
$$
e
$$
so this means that following must hold true:

$$
\frac{1}{e} \leq \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) \leq e
$$

This means that the limit of $f(x)$ lies between these two values and therefore, the limit of $f(x)$ does not converge. 
Is this proof enough? 
Or am I supposed to mention that $f(x)$ oscillates between these two points?

Comment: Isn't it just $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-\sin x}$?

Comment: I guess you mistyped some signs in the question and you can please explain from where did you get a 1 in the second step?

Comment: If $f(x)=2$ for all $x$ then $\frac1e<f(x)<e$. So a _constant_ does not have a limit at infinity??????????

Answer (score 1):

As @DavidC.Ullrich hints, you do need to mention the oscillation, or at least an important consequence of it: in each period of $\sin x$, $\exp(-\sin x)$ achieves both its extrema, so there is no point beyond which it's always within $\varepsilon$ of one of them (at least not for $0<\varepsilon<e-1/e$, let alone arbitrarily small $\varepsilon>0$, as a limit's existence would require).